# iPod 5 charger isn't working! What do I do?

Tags: ipod-touch, power

I have A ipod 5. Every time I go to charge it with a dynex or apple charger it doesn't charge. The bar stays red for over an hour. I'm thinking that I have a short in my charger. I don't know what to do. Please help?

Comment: I meant to say I don't know what to do please help

Comment: Did you tried using only the USB cable (without the power adapter) ?

Comment: I know right that is exactly what is happening to me. I have bought over 15 chargers now and Im starting to think its my ipod

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing if your charge is dead, try using a USB cable connected to your Mac, to charge it that way.

> To charge iPod, connect it directly to a computer's USB port (not a
>   keyboard) and make sure standby, hibernation, or sleep mode is turned
>   off. Important: iPod will stop charging if the computer it's connected
>   to enters standby, hibernation, or sleep mode.

If you have a volt meter then check the pins of the cable coming out of the charger.